# How to do advanced select in selection formula?

Tags: crystal-reports

I have two tables: `TAB_A(id_a)` and `TAB_B(id_b, id_a, price)`.

Condition: `price >500`.

I want select only once TAB_A and all TAB_B when condition is true and nothing when condition is false.

`TAB_A(id_a) join TAB_B(id_a)`

How to do this in record-selection formula, or it is not possible?

It dosn't work. When: 
TAB_A(1) and TAB_B(1,1,200) 
TAB_A(1) and TAB_B(2,1,400) 
TAB_A(1) and TAB_B(3,1,600) 
It select me only last one, but I wont select all in this case.

edit:

My table looks like this:

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/io8mT.png
```

Sample values:

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Xv3R.png
```

IF 'Price >500' I want to have

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5CZat.png
```

If 'Price > 700' I want to have

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3Gin.png
```

Comment: 600 is > 500 so it is included; 200 is < 500 so it is excluded; 400 is < 500 so it is excluded.  Is this isn't what you want, then you need to be more explicit with your question's logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `inner` join the tables in the 'Database Expert' (on `id_a`).

Create a record-selection formula:

```
{TAB_B.price}>500
```

Comment: Please update your question and post a picture of your table linking and the full text of your record-selection formula.